# How to completely stop / terminate a task that has already been submitted to an ExecutorService in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, executorservice, futuretask

Problem : I have an use case where I want to cancel a task that has already been submitted to an executor service. future.cancel() is not helpful to me as the task does not go to wait() / sleep() state during the execution. Also, adding `isInterrupted()` is not scalable because of the following reasons,

1. Many other services are called during the execution and using `isInterrupted()` before each call is ugly.
2. If suppose one of the service calls in one of the submitted tasks takes more than X milliseconds, I would want to abort the task and free up the tread.

Here is a sample code on how I am using future.cancel() right now. Is there a way where I can completely abort the submitted task / kill the thread executing the task in the main() function without disturbing the other submitted tasks.

```
public class Main {

    ExecutorService executorService = newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Future<Integer> test = new Main().sample();

        try {
            test.get(0, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Throwing InterruptedException");
        } catch (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Throwing ExecutionException");
        } catch (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Throwing TimeoutException");
        } finally {
            System.out.println(test.cancel(true));
        }
        System.out.println("main() COMPLETED");
    }

    private Future<Integer> sample() {
        return executorService.submit(() -> {
                System.out.println("sample() STARTED");
                anotherSample();
                System.out.println("sample() COMPLETED");
                return 1;
        });
    }

    private void anotherSample() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("anotherSample() STARTED");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                // do nothing
            }
            System.out.println("anotherSample() COMPLETED");
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Throwing TimeoutException
sample() STARTED
anotherSample() STARTED
true
main() COMPLETED
anotherSample() COMPLETED
sample() COMPLETED
```

Comment: Since Future.cancel() just interrupts the thread and not terminates the execution of the task, I would then need to use isInterrupted() check everywhere which is not scalable in my case as there are lots of dependent service calls involved. Also, I would want to terminate the tasks if the execution is not complete within X ms.

Comment: Timing out on a future is not terminating the execution of the task.

Comment: anotherSample() method seems a bit ugly, i do not see if there is an exit option/way from the for loop inside this method, it will try to finish the thing until i reaches 10000, even whatever you do outer of this thread/block.  so better use a wait/notify like code break the for loop.